# Django not looking in correct template folder when changing initially loaded app

Tags: python, django

in an Django project I have two apps named `file-management` and `docs`. As I first created the file management app my base `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('file_management.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('file_management/',include('file_management.urls')),
    path('docs/',include('docs.urls')),
]
```

In the `file_management` folder I then have an `urls.py` that defines where to look for templates:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="file_management"),
    path('<int:file_id>/', index),
]
```

And in the `docs` folder the `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="docs"),
    path('<docs_page>/', index),
]
```

Like this everything works fine and I can use the links `{% url 'docs' %}` and `{% url 'file_management' %}` and the admin page can be accessed via `/admin`.

Now if I change the base `urls.py` so that it points to `docs.urls` instead of `file_management.urls` for `''` like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('docs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('file_management/',include('file_management.urls')),
    path('docs/',include('docs.urls')),
]
```

I land on the correct `docs` page when loading the project. But if I click on a link I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist at /file_management/`. It seems Django is looking for the template in the wrong folders:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/anaconda3/envs/ct_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/anaconda3/envs/ct_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/sharOnStoNe/plotary/standalone/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/sharOnStoNe/plotary/shared/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/sharOnStoNe/plotary/file_management/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/sharOnStoNe/plotary/docs/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/fiedler/anaconda3/envs/ct_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bootstrap4/templates/docs/file_management.html (Source does not exist)
```

What did I do wrong in my URL setup here?

The `views.py` of `file_management` looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import StandaloneFileForm
from .models import StandaloneFile
from django.conf import settings
import os

# Create your views here.

def index(request,file_id=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        for file in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            request.FILES['file'] = file
            form = StandaloneFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                _new = form.save(commit=False)
                _new.save()
    else:
        form = StandaloneFileForm()
    all_entries = StandaloneFile.objects.all()

    if file_id:
        print("Received file id {} to delete.".format(file_id))
        if StandaloneFile.objects.filter(id=file_id).exists():
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,StandaloneFile.objects.get(id=file_id).file.url))
            StandaloneFile.objects.filter(id=file_id).delete()
        else:
            print("File does not exist.")

    return render(request, 'file_management/file_management.html',{"form":form,"entries":all_entries})
```

The `views.py` of `docs` like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.

def index(request,docs_page='docs'):
    return render(request, 'docs/'+docs_page+'.html',{"page":docs_page})
```

Comment: can you share your view methods and last state of your base urls.py?

Comment: I made an edit to inlcude the views and current state of base urls.py.

Comment: Your view methods seems to be ok. What is the link that raises the error?

Comment: After changing the empty path to docs.urls only the link to docs is still working. The links to file_management and /admin are both not pointing to the correct locations.

Comment: I suspect you have error in your html template. when you click a link does it converts into corrent url?

Comment: In the template I link to `<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'file_management' %}">File Management</a>`. and this opens `/file_management/`. With the old setup of the base `urls.py` this displayed the correct template. Now I get the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base `urls.py` you have you have

```
path('', include('docs.urls')),
```

and in your docs app you have urls

```
path('', index, name="docs"),
path('<docs_page>/', index),
```

this `<docs_page>` is like a variable. anything after `/` would be saved in this `docs_page` so that means any url say `localhost:8000/anything` will be handled by your docs apps url/view method. because then `docs_page='anything'`
in the same way `localhost:8000/file_management` also gets handled by your docs app because then `docs_page='file_management'`
thats why you are getting template error cause your template is not present in doc app.
**edit:**

1. firstly in your base `url.py` remove redundent include of `path('docs/',include('docs.urls')),` because you are already including the urls in first line.
2. prefix your apps url with appropiate prefix. like

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('files', view_for_files, name="file_home"),
        path('file_management/<file_id>', view_for_specific_file, name='file_with_id')
```

and your file_management view would be something like

```
def view_for_specific_file(request, file_id):
    # your file_id now contains whatever was passed 
    # from ..:8080/file_management/5
    # so file_id = 5 now do what you want to do with it
```

Comment: Okay that is pointing in the right direction I believe! What I actually tried to do with `docs_page`  and `file_id` is that this value would be given like `localhost:8000/file_management/5` or `localhost:8000/docs/intro`. How would I achieve this?

Comment: I tried to to use the approach from your edit and changed the base `urls.py` to `urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('docs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('file_management/',include('file_management.urls')),
]` and the docs `urls.py` to `urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', index, name="docs_home"),
    path('docs/<docs_page>', index, name="docs_page"),
]`. Unfortunately now I get a page not found error.

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in plotary.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    /docs/ [name='docs_home']
    /docs/<docs_page> [name='docs_page']
    admin/
    file_management/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: yes, you should try localhost:8000/docs, i think you have a misunderstanding how MVC works. please read django documentation. You are tring to handle two urls with single controller.

Comment: if you want to show docs app page for empty url, try changing docs urls.py to handle empty url like  path('', index, name="docs_page")

Comment: My docs `urls.py` currently looks like this: urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('docs/', index),
    path('docs/<docs_page>/', index),
] and my base urls.py is urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('docs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('file_management/',include('file_management.urls')),
] This leads to a NoReverseMatch error for empty url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216718/discussion-between-mursalin-and-axel).

Answer (score 1):

For the templates issue

Based on the information I'm assuming you dont have the file_management app registered in your settings.py Templates

```
In your file_management view you render with the following:

'file_management/file_management.html'

This will work if your structure looks like this

Root
    file_management
        templates
            file_management
                file_management.html
                

Or

Root
    templates
        file_management
            file_management.html
```

In your settings verify the following:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'docs', 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'file_management', 'templates'),
            
            
...
```

This will register combine all your templates folders into a single logical directory.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/

Be sure to serve static and media files too

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Extracted from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

I recommend the following...

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('docs.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('file_management/',include('file_management.urls')),
    # path('docs/',include('docs.urls')),
]
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="docs"),
    path('<docs_page>/', index),
]

or i assume you want this

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="docs"),
    path('docs/<docs_page>/', index),
]
```

Optional Step... with Urls make sure to add namespaces

```
path('', include('docs.urls', namespace='docs')),
path('file_management/', include('file_management.urls', namespace='file_management')),

app_name = 'docs'
urlpatterns = [ ... ]

app_name = 'file_management'
urlpatterns = [ ... ]

# Usage example ... return redirect('docs:index')  return redirect('file_management:index')
```

Let me know if this fixed it. It's hard to pinpoint the issue without your settings.py .